# Htaccess hotlink prevention except certain files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to make hotlinking impossible for all files ending with (jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js) except the pngs that begin with "apple-touch*"? This is what i am having right now but it doesn't work:

```
#Apple Icons
RewriteRule ^\/?apple-touch.*\.png$ applicon.png

#HOTLINKING PREVENTION
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/?apple-touch.*\.png$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$ - [NC,F,L]
```